How can I access specific parts of a solutions manual that is not locally available?
I am currently facing a challenge in accessing specific problems from the solutions manual of a textbook that is crucial for my studies. The manual in question is not available in any library near me, but I have identified that it is available at the Oklahoma State University Library as per the listings on worldcat.org.
Specifically, I only need the solutions for the problems of chapter 2 (problems 2.1 to 2.20) from the manual. Since I only require a small portion of the manual, I am seeking guidance on how I might be able to obtain access to these sections. I am looking for legal and ethical ways, possibly through library loan systems, academic sharing, or other legitimate means.
Does anyone have advice or resources that could guide me on how to proceed with obtaining access to these specific parts of the solutions manual?
Name of book: Solutions manual to accompany 'Flight stability and automatic control' by Robert Nelson

Ask your (academic) librarian. They are able to arrange inter-library loans.
You should also contact the library having the resource directly.
For a small fee they may reproduce digitally the required sections and email it to you (when copying up to a certain % of the book no copyrights are violated, your librarian will assist you).

It is highly unlikely that you would be able to get the solution manual (either full or part) using the methods you mentioned. The solution manuals are normally part of learning resources that are, in most of the cases, only given to instructors or professors, who are using the book for the course. And they are not allowed to share the manual with students. You can try your luck by either emailing the professor, who is using the book or contacting the OSU library. I am kinda certain that you might not get positive response from either source. You should try your luck at online student forums. I also urge you to post your related questions to other relevant SE forums (Drone and Aircraft SE should be the most suitable in your case).
